# React-Native app not updating in android device (Windows 10)

Tags: android, react-native, reload

I´ve been trying to build my first app with react native but when I change the App.js the changes are not reflected when I run the app on my anroid device.
I even tried putting in comments all code to see if something changes but remains the same.
I´m using react-native-cli: 2.0.1 and react-native: 0.53.3
Sorry if writing wrong but English is not my "native" language :V

My code:

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMDMW.png)

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRlG4.png)

Hope you can help me, but I will keep trying.

I realized that when the app is running in a virtual device, the changes are reflected.

Answer (score 1):

For real device, shake your phone to open the debug panel.
Make sure the **Enable hot reloading** option is switched on.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

This is not the main problem, but it's better to have a `<View></View>` component to wrap the `Text` component. So you can add more component and apply styling later on.